# ASP .NET Core 2.1 Identity: UserRoles is null

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

In my Razor web app, I've tried to get a list of users and their roles the following ways:

```
_userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role).Result;
_dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(u => u.Role);
_userManager.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).ToList();
```

And UserRoles is always null. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my Startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Here is my model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my OnModelCreating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(au =>
        {
            au.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles).WithOne(e => e.User).HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId).IsRequired();
        });

        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(ar =>
        {
            ar.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles).WithOne(e => e.Role).HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).IsRequired();
        });

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(aur =>
        {
            aur.HasOne(ur => ur.Role).WithMany(r => r.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).IsRequired();
            aur.HasOne(ur => ur.User).WithMany(r => r.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId).IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you seed data to `ApplicationUserRole` table?

Comment: Yes, I have seeded my user with roles and I have tested that they work. :(

Comment: Share us the code you seed data, and the records in database.

Comment: Was a solution found?